# Global Name Not Defined in Python

Tags: python, oop, list

Am new to Python OOP. Please dont be harsh. Here is my code which calculates which is  the fastest time of an athlete from a list and displays them. But When Running, I get this error:

```
z= add.mylist.min()
NameError: global name 'add' is not defined
```

My Code:

```
class Athlete:

    def add(self):
        list=[]
        mylist=[]

        for i in range(2):

            self.name = raw_input("Enter name: ")
            self.fastest_time = input("time: ")
            list.append(self.name)
            mylist.append(self.fastest_time)
        print "Names: ",list
        print "Fastest times: ",mylist

    def display(self):
        z= add.mylist.min()
        w= add.mylist.index(z)
        print "Minimum time: ",z
        print "Name of athelte with fastest time: ",list[w]

x = Athlete()
x.add()
x.display()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to refer to methods on the instance with the `self` parameter. In addition, your `add()` method needs to *return* the `mylist` variable it generates, you cannot refer to method local variables as attributes on methods:

```
def display(self):
    mylist = self.add()
    z = min(mylist)
    w = mylist.index(z)

def add(self):
    list=[]
    mylist=[]

    for i in range(2):

        self.name = raw_input("Enter name: ")
        self.fastest_time = input("time: ")
        list.append(self.name)
        mylist.append(self.fastest_time)
    print "Names: ",list
    print "Fastest times: ",mylist

    return mylist
```

That is what `self` is *for*, as a reference point to find instance attributes and other methods on the same object.

You may want to *rename* `list` to something that does not shadow the built-in type.

Comment: I tried your code and This is what is get:

    z= self.add.mylist.min()
    AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'mylist'

Comment: In the display method, how i will be able to list the fastest athlete based on the minimum time from the list. Thank You

Comment: Getting This Now:
z = min(list)
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable

Comment: That's because `list()` is a built in type - check the code in the question, the variable is `mylist`. This is a good show of why it's a terrible idea to use the names of built-ins as variable names.

Answer (score 1):

Martijn has already answered your question, so here are some remarks and code style tips:

1. New-style classes derive from `object`
2. You have both athlete names and their times, those belong together as key-value pairs in a dictionary instead of two separate lists
3. Don't use `print` statements inside class methods, a class method should return an object that you then can print
4. what if you have more then 2 athletes for which you want to enter the time? If you make the number of athletes an argument of your function, you can add a variable number of athlethes
5. give descriptive variable names (not `mylist`) and don't use names of builtin functions (like `list`) as variable name
6. variables that you want to use throughout your class can be initalized in an `__init__`method.
7. For printing, use the `format` function instead of using commas
8. use `if __name__ == '__main__'` so that [your Python file can act as either reusable modules or as standalone program](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/tutor-what-is-if-name-main-for.htm)

Taking these into account, I would rewrite your code to something like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Athlete(object): # see (1)
    def __init__(self): # see (6)
        self.athlete_times = defaultdict(str) # see (2)

    def add_athletes_and_times(self, n): # see (4)
        for i in range(n):
            self.name = raw_input("Enter name: ")
            self.fastest_time = input("time (in seconds): ") 
            self.athlete_times[self.fastest_time] = self.name

    def get_fastest_time(self):
        return min(self.athlete_times) # see (3)

if __name__ == '__main__': # see (8)
    x = Athlete()
    x.add_athletes_and_times(2)
    for fast_time in x.athlete_times:
        print "The fastest time of athlete {0} is {1} seconds.".format(
                        x.athlete_times[fast_time], fast_time) # see (7)
    fastest_time = x.get_fastest_time()
    print "The overall fastest time is: {0} seconds for athlete {1}.".format(
                       fastest_time, x.athlete_times[fastest_time])
```

Comment: `defaultdict` is not needed here, a regular python `dict` would work just as well. Otherwise, nice job cleaning up the code!

Comment: Woww BIo..Great Help..Atleast I learned something from You Ty